# Why does my HTML code return [object HTMLFormElement]?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to coding so I apologise for the obvious question, but I'm attempting to create a code in HTML which takes a user input value and prints the value underneath in the paragraph tag. If this doesn't make sense, here is my code so far and an image of the file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" id="theInput" name="theInput">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction(){
        var input = document.forms["form"];
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = input
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
      Press me!
    </button>
    <p id="message"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

Thank you!

Comment: Because `forms` is a reference to the `<form>` in your document. It is not the `<input>` element, and it is not the *value* of the `<input>` element, which is what you want.

Comment: I haven't seen `document.forms` (or any accessor like that) used in a _very_ long time. I would recommend using more modern JS like `querySelector` etc (as shown in the answer below).

Comment: Note: **JavaScript is *not* Java**, despite the similarity in their name.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below function to get the value from the text field using JS. `Document.form` is the wrong way to take the input text.

```
  function myFunction(){
    var input = document.getElementById("theInput").value;
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = input
  }
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: That seems to be working! Thank you so much